# generating pdf using UseFrontEnd

Tags: front-end, pdf-format, linux, remote-access

I run mathematica on a remote server and run it in batch mode using /math -noprompt -script 'scriptname.m' &

Now, I use ssh -X to connect to the server. The server is linux based and my computer is a mac. I use x11 forwarding.

I would like to generate PDFs in the above mentioned 'script.m'. In my code, how should I incorporate UseFrontEnd? should I invoke it first using ConnectToFrontEnd[] ? Should I use UseFrontEnd[Export["blah.pdf",fig]] or is it a one time thing? 
Also, when using the UseFrontEnd command, is it required that I do ssh -X/Y or is it sufficient if I do ssh?

I greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks.

P.S - I am using mathematica 8

Comment: this might help: http://superuser.com/questions/381807/convert-mathematica-to-pdf-via-command-line

Comment: not exactly. How do I use UseFrontEnd together with Export? and should I do that EVERYTIME I export a file to pdf?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315464/exporting-a-plot-as-an-image-in-mathematica-on-a-machine-without-x11-ie-withou   this seems to help. But still, I don't know if I need to code Needs[Jlink`] and then UseFrontEnd[Export[]] everytime I export.

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient if you just do `ssh` - I was able to use the following commands without X11 forwarding.

After you `ssh` to the machine with *Mathematica* and invoke *MathKernel* you can do in the interactive session:

```
UFE = UsingFrontEnd
(* Out[4]= UsingFrontEnd *)
plot = UFE @ Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2}]
(* Out[5]= -Graphics- *)
UFE @ Export["/home/username/picture.jpg",plot]
(* Out[6]= /home/username/picture.jpg *)
```

And you can see the generated picture:

[image: sample image generated in interactive session in MathKernel]

The `UFE = UsingFrontEnd` line is to make the input lines shorter. Of course you could write `plot = UsingFrontEnd @ Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2}]`.

After inspecting the output of `monitorlm` (*Mathematica* network license manager) I think that the first invocation of `UsingFrontEnd` starts a *SubMathematica* process and the same process is used in subsequent `UsingFrontEnd` commands. The *SubMathematica* process is terminated when the interactive *MathKernel* session is closed.

I'm sure things are very similar when using a `.m` script.

**edit** I am using *Mathematica* 7.0.1.0 installed on *Ubuntu* 11.10 **end edit**

**edit 2** After OP's comment I chcecked that to `Plot[]` and `Export[]` you don't need `UsingFrontEnd`. So the following works fine:

```
plot = Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2}]
(* Out[1]= -Graphics- *)
Export["/home/username/picture.jpg",plot]
(* Out[2]= /home/username/picture.jpg *)
```

The [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UsingFrontEnd.html?q=UsingFrontEnd&lang=en) says that `UsingFrontEnd` is necessary for functions like `NotebookWrite[]`, when used from *MathKernel*. **end edit 2**

Comment: this looks promising. I'll try. So you say I have to say UsingFrontEnd every time before I invoke some kind of plotting command or export graphics? Is there a way to just turn the switch on at the beginning of the script and turn it off at the end?

Comment: welll it seems you don't need the `UsingFrontEnd` command to `plot = Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2}]` and `Export["/home/username/output.jpg",plot]`. The [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UsingFrontEnd.html?q=UsingFrontEnd&lang=en) says that `UsingFrontEnd` is neccesary for `NotebookWrite[]` and similar functions (I have used it to `NotebookPrint[]` some time ago).