# Mathematica script, called from Windows task scheduler, does not export graphics

Tags: graphics, export, scripting

When I run the following script from command line,

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ConnectToFrontEnd[];
resultChart = UseFrontEnd[JuliaSetPlot[0.365 - 0.37 I]];
UseFrontEnd[Export["test.png", resultChart]];
CloseFrontEnd[];
```

the graphic file gets written out fine. In fact, the calls to `ConnectToFrontEnd, UseFrontEnd, CloseFrontEnd` are not even necessary.

However, if I call this script from Windows task scheduler, the function `ConnectToFrontEnd` returns True, but then an error is returned:

```
Rasterize::type : Notebook[ -- omitted --] cannot be rasterized.
```

I am aware of these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315464/exporting-a-plot-as-an-image-in-mathematica-on-a-machine-without-x11-ie-withou), [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/generating-pdf-using-usefrontend) questions, however I do not know what to do now here.

Comment: There is the builtin `UsingFrontEnd`, so you don't need `UseFrontEnd` from J/Link.  But neither `JuliaSetPlot`, nor `Export` need it.  (`Export` should make use of it internally).  I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but what happens if you drop the unneeded parts?

Comment: In case you suspect front end trouble, to test if a front end is available, check that `Head@UsingFrontEnd[$FrontEnd] === FrontEndObject`

Comment: I haven't personally tried this before, so YMMV...  I would switch to UsingFrontEnd and then ensure that when the task scheduler runs your script it has access to a desktop session.  Kinda like on X, the Windows FE requires this to do just about everything...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. `Head@UsingFrontEnd[$FrontEnd]===FrontEndObject` returns True. Switching to `UsingFrontEnd` did not help. Running the task with the option checked "only run if user is logged on" (which I interpret as making sure that there is access to a desktop session) does work! I am not an admin, so I am not sure if that is an option in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some experiments with MMA on Windows and it seems like silent FE execution (when a user is not logged on) is not working for functions that need to execute FE (even in the background). I suspect there might be a way to resolve it if proper permissions are set, but I don't know if it's worth it, besides this might be not available for all users.

There is an easier way though. If there is an Internet connectivity, I can suggest using the Wolfram cloud to evaluate and render the object. This script works perfectly in a task scheduler whether a user is logged on or not.

```
resultChart = JuliaSetPlot[0.365 - 0.37 I];
CloudConnect["...","..."]
co=CloudObject["temp"];
CloudEvaluate@Export[co, resultChart,"PNG"]
Export["testcloud.png",CloudImport[co],"PNG"];
DeleteFile[co];
CloudDisconnect[];
```